# Deck-Building tag too broad

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [deck-building](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deck-building) applies to two very different things:

1. The act of deciding which cards will go into a TCG/CCG/LCG deck to be played (IE MtG, YuGiOh, Android: Netrunner)
2. A genre of game in which a deck is built and used as the game progresses (IE Domninion, Ascension)

Should these tags be separated as they are two very distinct meanings for deck building?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are currently 78 open questions tagged with [deck-building](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deck-building). Of those, approximately 70 are questions about the processes, strategies, card choices, rules, etc. involved in building a deck. This basically corresponds to your first point. The rest use the tag to either refer to deck building games as a category, or in place of a specific game tag in that category.

So, I propose that the best solution here is to keep the [deck-building](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deck-building) tag for questions about building decks in any game (and modify the tag wiki accordingly), and to retag the other questions as appropriate, either by simply removing the tag, replacing it with a specific game tag, or replacing it with a different type of tag (such as [identify-this-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) if relevant).

Comment: I think this is what we should do, how exactly does it work on meta, do I accept this answer?

Answer (score 4):

I think a simple move would be to separate the tags. In other words, it would separate them into [deck-builder](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deck-builder) and [deck-building](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deck-building).

However, those names might be a bit too similar, especially when you take ESL users into account, so something like [deck-builder](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deck-builder) and [deck-advice](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deck-advice) might work?

Comment: Perhaps `deck-construction` and `deck-builder`? And of course the content of the wiki in the tooltip will help.

Comment: I don't think a tag about the deck building genre of games would be useful

Comment: Do we have questions, aside from [identify-this-game], that are about deck-building games as a genre? If not, then adding a tag for it seems unnecessary.